# Adding mild BGM to a full length of a video file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, mp3

I have a video file (about 6 mins) and a BGM file (about 2 mins). I need to add the BGM to my video file for entire 6 mins without reducing my original audio content of my video file,

I tried the following, but it's reducing my video file's audio content.

```
ffmpeg -i ${oldVideoFile} -filter_complex "amovie=video/bgm1.mp3:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB[aud];[0:a][aud]amix[a]" -map 0:v -map '[a]' -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 256k -shortest ${newVideoFile}
```

```
ffmpeg -i ${oldVideoFile} -stream_loop -1 -i video/bgmo.mp3 -shortest -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -c:v copy ${newVideoFile}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -i ${oldVideoFile} -stream_loop -1 -i video/bgm.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amix=duration=first[a]" -map 0:v -map '[a]' -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 256k ${newVideoFile}`